# Excel formula for subtracting down to zero then from another cell

Tags: excel

I have been trying to create a formula for about an hour now and have gotten nowhere so I am looking for some help. I am trying to create a formula that when an expense is above what was budgeted for it, rather than have the budget go negative, it is reduced to zero and the remaining balance if pulled from savings.
Where I really begin to encounter problems is when I do this for more than one expense.

***Sample Budget:***
[image]

So for Food, I budgeted $600 (D2) but spent $820 (D1). I want the sheet to read the money remaining for Food (D2) to be $0 and then the money remaining for Savings (D5) to be $39,780.
But things get much more complicated when we find out that we also overspent on Vacations which makes money remaining for Vacations (D4) to be $0 and money remaining in Savings to be $38,280 because it covered the overflow costs of both Food and Vacations (and would have covered any overspending from Clothing as well, if there had been any).

I am stumped on this problem. I have tried several approaches and would really appreciate any help you guys could give on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you've got to do is, in column D (remaining), make the formula in cell D2 (for example):

```
=IF(C2<B2,0,C2-B2)
```

Then for savings, it's equal to your starting amount (40000), minus what you spent, plus what you budgeted, minus the "remaining" amount (which I assume was already pulled out of savings):

```
=40000-SUM(B2:B4)+SUM(C2:C4)-SUM(D2:D4)
```

[image]